# After assign useState values but got undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I assign multiple objects in one `useState` and then fetch the data from the database using the redux toolkit and then defined values for those objects but when I do `console.log` it shows me a state value is undefined but `console.log` the fetch data from the database is successful.

### here is the code

```
const { data } = useGetConfigQuery();

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data?.mailgun_api_key);

    const configData = {
        mailgun_api_key: data?.mailgun_api_key,
        mailgun_username: data?.mailgun_username,
        mailgun_url: data?.mailgun_url,
        email_id_for_mail_sent: data?.email_id_for_mail_sent,
        isDiscountAvailable: data?.isDiscountAvailable,
        discounted_amount: data?.discounted_amount,
        min_amount_scheme_started: data?.min_amount_scheme_started,
        max_amount_scheme: data?.max_amount_scheme,
        razorpay_key: data?.razorpay_key,
        razorpay_secret: data?.razorpay_secret,
        razorpay_company_name: data?.razorpay_company_name,
    };

    const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(configData);

    console.log(config.mailgun_api_key);

    console.log(config);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setConfig({ ...config, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };
```

### the redux part

```
export const configApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getConfig: builder.query({
            query: () => ({
                url: `${CONFIG_API_URL}`,
                method: "GET",
            }),
            keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
            providesTags: ["Configuration"],
        }),
        updateConfig: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${CONFIG_API_URL}`,
                method: "PUT",
                body: data,
                credentials: "include",
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["Configuration"],
        }),
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you initially define configData, the data object from useGetConfigQuery() might not have been populated yet, so the values will be undefined.**

```
import { useGetConfigQuery } from 'path/to/your/apiSlice'; // Import the query hook

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetConfigQuery(); // Retrieve the data and loading state

  const configData = {
    mailgun_api_key: data?.mailgun_api_key,
    mailgun_username: data?.mailgun_username,
    // ... other properties
  };

  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const [config, setConfig] = useState(configData);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the config state when the data changes
    setConfig(configData);
  }, [data]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setConfig({ ...config, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  // Render loading state while fetching data
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  console.log(config.mailgun_api_key);
  console.log(config);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render your component UI here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Thanks for the answer now I can see the data in fields